# Error: The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, FragementTest, String)

Tags: android

Im trying to Use Fragements. But in MainActivity.java file the `transaction.add(R.id.my_layout, testfrag, "");`not Initiated correctly.please find below the code i used.

```
package com.example.testtabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import com.example.testtabs.R;



public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {


    TabHost tab;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         FragementTest testfrag=new FragementTest();
        FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.my_layout, testfrag, "");//Error is here

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
  >
```

```
Error: The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, FragementTest, String)
```

**Fragement.test**

```
package com.example.testtabs;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class FragementTest extends Fragment {

    public FragementTest() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragement, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: what is a FragmentTest?

Comment: Does your `FragmentTest` extend `Fragment`?

Comment: Cast to (Fragment). You surely extend Fragment(v4) in FragmentTest.

Comment: @AndrewT. please find the code i've edited

Answer (score 19, accepted):

change:

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

to:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

or---

change:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

to

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: Now im getting FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager(); method Error
Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Comment: use getSupportFragmentManager() instead also your activity must be Fragment activity.

Comment: check my edited ans instead of changing the imports for FragmentManager change it for Fragment.

Answer (score 2):

All the Fragment should be android.app.Fragment. If you want to use android.support.v4.app.Fragment, you should use getSupportFragmentManager() to get the Manager.

Comment: You should add "g" "getSupportFragmentManager();"

Answer (score 1):

Its working for me:

Instead of using getFragmentManager use  getSupportFragmentManager();